# assignment from incompatiable pointer type C

Tags: c, pointers

Say I want to read in a list of pages
name of max 19 character, e.g.  4
(Number of page) Name1 Name2 Name3
Name4

I am trying to use a global 2D array
to store the page number and page
name, I got an error saying assignment
from incompatiable pointer type...

Thanks

```
static int nPages;
static char** pageName;

int main(void){
  scanf(" %d", &nPages);

  pageName = (char *)malloc(nPages*sizeof(char));
  for(int i=0; i < nPages ;i++){
    pageName[i] = (char *)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    scanf(" %s", pageName[i]);
  }

//Free Memory Here of coz. 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to declare i *BEFORE* the for loop

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies right there:

```
pageName = (char *)malloc(nPages*sizeof(char));
```

pageName is a `char **`, not a `char *`. So it should read:

```
pageName = malloc(nPages*sizeof(char*)); // sizeof(char *), and no need to cast
```

**EDIT:** removed the cast

Comment: Thanks but how would the char length of max 19 be expressed in this case ?

Comment: Whoops, i get it, thats just for the first malloc. Thanks =]

Comment: Because I disagree with what "it should read". I don't like casts in my mallocs.

Comment: @Martinho Sorry about that, I'm primarily a C++ programmer.

Comment: @Etienne: changed to +1. FWIW, this is one of those situations that shows that C isn't strictly a subset of C++. Without the cast, it won't compile in C++.

Comment: C++ programmers using `malloc` and casting the result is roughly as offensive as English speakers using words from other languages and botching the pronunciation or meaning... :-)

Comment: @R.. I prefer using `new`, but whenever I have to write C and I have to use `malloc`, I can't help but say "oh, this returns a `void *`, better cast it, because implicit conversions are _evil_."

Comment: On the other hand, explicit conversions are evil. They're a red flag that you're doing something you shouldn't be doing. The C language has exactly (well, almost exactly) the right set of implicit conversions so that you never need to make them explicit when you're doing something reasonable.

Answer (score 5):

[Never cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858). It hides compiler warnings that actually help you, and it's never necessary so it just adds clutter. You should use:

```
pageName = malloc(nPages * sizeof *pageName);
```

Note how this is free from repetitions of the type name of `pageName`. Here, `sizeof *pageName` means "the size of the object pointed at by `pageName`", i.e. "the size of a character pointer". You should expect a `sizeof` expression as `malloc()`'s argument very often.

Also, `sizeof (char)` is always 1 in C, so that particular expression, it can be argued, adds more clutter than it helps make the code safe.

Answer (score 0):

Your defined `pageName` as `char **` but when calling malloc to initialize the pointer, you use a cast to `(char *)`. Maybe that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `char*` to `char**` at your first `malloc` line. Just drop the `(char*)` cast - C handles `void*` to `char**` conversion automatically.

Answer (score 0):

`char*` and `char**` are two different types, and you can't freely assign the first to the latter.

Having said that, you have to do a two-step initialization. First, you have to `malloc()` space for `nPages` string:

```
pageName = (char**) malloc(nPages * sizeof(char*));
```

then, you have to `malloc()` space for each `pageName`:

```
for (i = 0; i < nPages; ++i) {
    pageName[i] = (char*) malloc(20);
}
```